Get Closed-Form Solution for Firm Cost with Recursion in Multi-Firm, Multi-Product Setup
I am working on a problem where I need to derive the cost for a firm producing a product, considering multiple products and firms. Specifically, there are $N$ products, and for each product, there are $F$ firms producing it. Each firm is denoted by $f$ or $f'$, and each product is denoted by $k$ or $k'$. I am trying to determine a closed-form solution for the cost of firm
$f$ producing product $k$, if possible.
Problem Setup:
Firm $f$ that produces product $k$ needs to purchase all other products $k'$ in the economy to be able to produce $k$. However, firm $f$ will only purchase from one firm producing each $k'$. When selecting which firm to buy from, firm $f$ will choose the firm that offers the minimum quality-adjusted cost of the product among the firms it encounters. This introduces recursivity into the problem.
I have the following equation describing the cost:
$$
c(f_k)^{1-s} = a + b  \sum_{k} \left( \min_{f'_{k'} \in S(f_k, k')} \frac{c(f'_{k'})}{q(f'_{k'})} \right)^{1-s}
$$
Where:

$c(f_k)$ is the cost of firm $f$ producing product $k$.
$s$ is an integer greater than $1$.
$a$ and $b$ are positive constants.
$S(f_k, k')$ is the set of firms $f'_{k'}$ that produce product $k'$ which are available to firm $f_k$
$q(f'_{k'})$ is the quality assigned to firm $f'_{k'}$

Attempted Vectorization
I attempted to solve this problem by converting the equation into a vector format, but I haven't made much progress. The vectorized equation looks like this:
$$
C^{1-s} = A + b \ast \left( \sum_{k'} \text{rowmax} \left( A_{k'} \odot C^{1-s} \odot \frac{1}{Q^{1-s}}\right) \right) $$
Where:

$C$, $A$, and $Q$ are $(F \times N) \times 1$ vectors
$b$ is a scalar
$A_{k'}$ is a $(F \times N)\times (F \times N)$ matrix, where $A_{k'}(f_k, f'_{k'}) = 1$ if $f_k$
encounters $f'_{k'}$ when purchasing product $k'$, and 0 otherwise. Any firm not producing $k'$ will automatically be $0$.

What I'm Looking For
I would like guidance on how to derive a closed-form solution for $c(f_k)$ or how to handle this recursion. Specifically, is there a way to handle the recursion in the cost function and find a closed-form expression for $c(f_k)$? Any advice on how to approach this problem or simplify the equations would be greatly appreciated.
